# Monotonicity of consumer preferences

Tags: order-theory, economics

I'm learning about monotonicity and I can't seem to figure out what larger $x$ is and what is smaller $x$.

If I strictly prefer larger x when until $x<10$, what does that mean?

#### Context

The question is; Ben likes to drink beer. Let $x$ belonging to $[0, 20] = X$ be the possible number of beers he drinks. He strictly prefers larger $x$ until $x<10$ but he feels sick if $x\ge 10$. So he strictly prefers $x=0$ to any $x\ge 10$.

I've scoured the internet and can't find anything on what it means. Does it just mean that if he prefers larger x, he prefers a higher number? And if he prefers smaller $x$, he prefers a smaller number?

The topic comes under consumer theory, microeconomics.

Comment: Wait, … what? What do you mean by "larger x"? Larger than what?

Comment: Can you copy the exact context? This sounds like $x$ should be large/smaller than something (or as large/small as possible) for something to hold.

Answer (score 2):

It means that if he has to chose between 3 beer and 4, he's gonna chose 4 (because it's larger that 3)

If he have to chose between 7 and 10, he will chose 7 though! Because otherwise he feels sick

Is it clear?

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes I get it now cheers :)

Comment: "If he have to chose between 7 and 10, he will chose 7 though! Because otherwise he feels sick" but I think if he drank 10 beers, he prefers 0, so not having drunk beer at all

Comment: @user133613 If he has to choose between 10 and 0, he's gonna choose 0. Between 0 and 7, he'll choose 7. If this answer has been helpful, please accept it (there is a check below the vote count ;-) )